# Basic HTTP Authentication in IIS

Tags: .htaccess, iis, http-authentication, .htpasswd

Is it possible to do BOTH of these using a web.config file?  If not, what would be the easiest way to achieve them on an IIS server.

1. Protect a web-accessible folder via HTTP auth
2. Allow access from a specific username/password AND a specific IP address

This is possible using .htaccess and .htpasswd on Apache, but I need an IIS equivalent if one exists.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, providing those settings have not been locked at the server/site level. They can also be set from the IIS manager. This is probably a better question for website admins, though.